# comma seperated checkbox $_GET query request with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Trying to create a search function using multiple checkboxes, but seem to be only finding information related to $_POST requests.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="5">
```

What is the best way to get the query to look like this

```
search?fruit=1,2,3,4
```

Is there a way to do this non ajax?

Just to clarify...

Each value represents a different fruit.

Originally I did this

```
search?apple=1&orange=1
```

As I added more checkboxes, the query seemed inefficient.

I know that I can add the checkboxes into the array using the $_POST method

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="2">
```

As a few have suggested using this technique for a $_GET query would look something like this

```
search?fruit[]=1&fruit[]=2&fruit[]=5
```

So the question is really how to clean it up (comma seperated)

Comment: You need to set your form's **method** to `GET`

Comment: Checkboxes need distinct names; radio buttons share the name attribute.

Comment: ... or they need to be named with `[]` wherein PHP will receive them as an array `name="fruit[]"` but that will make the query string `search?fruit[]=1&fruit[]=2&fruit[]=5` If you want to make it a comma-separated list, you will need to script it.

Comment: Why would you want these comma-separated?  There's no way to do that without JavaScript (but you don't need to do it via AJAX).

Comment: reconstruct them using hidden input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE:** As others have pointed out, it isn't necessary to pass a single parameter with a comma-separated value to end up with an array or a comma-separated value on the server. Frameworks like PHP can handle this with no JavaScript required. You can simply give each checkbox the same "name" attribute. That will cause multiple parameters with the same name to be passed to the server, which is just fine. In fact, it is the same result you would get if you used a `<select multiptle="multiple">` element.

In PHP, if you use a name with square brackets at the end, like `fruit[]`, you can then get an array on the server with:

```
$_GET['fruit']
```

And if you want a comma-separated value on the server, you can use:

```
implode(',', $_GET['fruit'])
```

**But if you really want a single parameter with a comma-separated value, here is how you can do it:**

You can use a form with a hidden input. Set the form's "method" to `"get"` and the hidden input's "name" to `"fruit"`. Then add an event handler that sets the value of the hidden input to the comma-separated string when the form is submitted.

HTML:

```
<form id="fruitForm" action="search" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="fruit" />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" />apple</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" />banana</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3" />orange</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="4" />pineapple</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="5" />grapefruit</label><br />
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#fruitForm').submit(function() {
    var fruits = $('#fruitForm').find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');

    $('#fruitForm').find('input[name=fruit]').val(fruits);
});
```

Note: The checkbox elements do not have "name" attributes, so they do not get included in the form submission.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69VZe/1/)

Comment: You can just use `fruit[]` as the input name and PHP (and some other frameworks) will handle this automatically

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks John

Comment: @naomik - It may seem unnecessary, but it does what the OP wants. I think at least it is clear from the question (after it was edited) that the OP is aware of the alternatives.

Comment: @JohnS, fair enough. If you edit the answer to acknowledge this, I can remove my downvote ^.^

Comment: @naomik - I have added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fruit[]` as the input name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="5">
```

You will get the following:

```
echo "<pre>", print_r($_GET["fruit"], true);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Use `checkbox` name as `fruit[]`. In php get the fruit array and converted as string using `implode()`

```
    <?php
       echo $fruits = implode(",",$_GET['fruit']); //1,2,3,4,5
    ?>
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="5">        
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
```